# Detecting spaces and applying to a variable

Tags: python, string, list, type-conversion

I have a string 'word words wordword' which is converted into a list using the .split method. I want to write code which will detect each space in the list and put the text beforehand into a variable. For example, if the string was 'word words wordword', I would want 'word' to be put in a variable, then every character after that space and before the next space into a different variable (and so on). So the result would be something like:

```
q=word
qq=words
qqq=wordword
```

Is there a function I could use to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you want to do that? split() will give you a list you can index into to access the individual words.

Comment: If you don't know beforehand how many spaces there are in your string, you can't assign each "word" to a different variable since you need an arbitrary number of variables. If that's the case, then you need to use a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you think of `(q,qq,qqq)=mystring.split()` ?